# 'Import getting Started Content' has encountered a problem

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I have created new spring starter project in SpringSuiteTool. I am getting this error when I created new spring starter project.

ArtifactTransferException: com.google.guava:guava:jar:10.0.1 failed to transfer from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.google.guava:guava:jar:10.0.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): The operation was cancelled. java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Answer (score 0):

Go to `{userdir}/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava`, delete `10.0.1` folder and re build the project